# How to separate Email addresses and iterate loop on base of Email counts to add values to MailAddressCollection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

In MVC I am receiving Value of multiple Email Address (Comma Separated) in text box from User as mentioned below:

```
string carbonCopyEmailReceiver = reviewContractPresenter.EmailCcReceiver;
```

Now I want to separate these Email addresses and iterate loop on base of Email counts to add values to CC that is MailAddressCollection.

```
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmailAddress))
{
//loop will goes here
  mail.CC.Add("user1@example.com");
}
```

Can please someone assist me?

Comment: [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `string.Split` method:

```
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmailAddress))
{
    foreach (string cc in carbonCopyEmailReceiver.Split(','))
    {
        mail.CC.Add(cc);
    }
}
```